# How can I program multiple low confidence responses in Chatterbot?

Tags: chatterbot

I want my error handling to have humor and personality.
according to docs, I can insert a default response for low confidence.
http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/chatterbot/logic/low_confidence.html
But I want to have the bot give a wide variety of low confidence responses.
Q: how do I code those up?

Answer (score -1):

as far as i can solve this problem you can use given code i think you can modify it as per use using if elseif

import logging

def get_random_response(input_statement, response_list):

```
 from random import choice
 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 logger.info(u'Selecting a response from list of {} options.'.format(
      len(response_list)
  ))
 return choice(response_list)
```

get_random_response('how are you',["i am good","doing well","missing you","thinking about you"])